# when changing source to wyswyg ckeditor skip span tag asp.net

Tags: asp.net, editor, html, ckeditor.net

I have a ckeditor when i click source to wyswyg from ckeditor toolbar it skips span tag my code is 
**original code**

```
       <div style="color: White; display: block; float: right; font-size: 11pt; font-style: italic; margin-right: 116px; margin-top: -85px; position: relative; width: 40px;">
<span id="Active"></span> of <span id="Total"></span>
     </div>
```

i see this code when clicking source button

```
<div style="color: White; display: block; float: right; font-size: 11pt; font-style: italic; margin-right: 116px; margin-top: -85px; position: relative; width: 40px;">
 of</div>
```

i have a situation where i cannot use asp.net server controls i saving page in database.
can anyone tell me how to fix that problem or should i change ckeditor to any other editor
please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known behavior in CKEditor. That's how it's supposed to work. There are a few workarounds [explained here](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9004).